# Open file stored in byte[] in webbrowser control

Tags: c#

Is there a way to take a byte[] and open the file rather than having to write it to disk and delete it when finished? They will be pdf files.

**Update 2**

```
if (e.Result is byte[])
            {
                byte[] message = (byte[])e.Result;
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(message))
                {
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    wbMessage.NavigateToStream(stream);
                }
            }
```

I scrapped this idea and used Adobe's COM object to display my PDFs

Comment: It all depends on what you are going to do with the file when you "open" it. If you are opening it inside your program yes you can, if you are trying to open it in a external program like Adobe Reader you can't.

Comment: Until I get a PDF viewer control i'm going to load it in a browser control which would use adobe reader

Answer (score 2):

`MemoryStream` has constructor that takes `byte[]`

Comment: updated the OP with what i'm trying. Also don't think I need the MemoryStream since it's already a byte[]

Comment: @Tsukasa it looks like you still should use a MemoryStream, but just pass that stream in to [`WebBrowser.DocumentStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: wpf equivalent to DocumentStream?

Comment: *Note:* This **will not work** as the web browser cannot properly read the memory stream of a PDF binary. So this answer is pretty useless.